# In eclipse mixed java+scala projects, how to avoid phantom compilation errors in java code that depends on scala?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I am working on mixed scala+java project in Eclipse. The problem I have is Eclipse reports "phantom" compilation errors on java classes that depend on scala. "Phantom" means that I can only see these errors when reading source code (red markers for missing types) but they are not reported in problems view nor they affect compilation. Also, when in Java code view, I cannot navigate to scala types with F3 (all scala types are marked red as not available).

Is there any way to solve this? My dependencies are both ways, so I cannot switch to  "scala first" or "java first" modes.

My versions are: Kepler + Scala IDE 3.0.2 + Scala 2.10

Comment: Use Intellij ;) It's the recommended IDE for Scala.

Comment: Great hint. Maybe I should also consider getting rid of scala and move to python or ruby to avoid my issues.

Comment: If you use Python, you might use PyCharm IDE. If you use ruby, you might use RubyMine. If you use C# you'd use Visual Studio. Bash a text editor. JS use sublime. etc etc etc.  See my point now??